# Unable to access VLAN host from VLAN interface in CentOS

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, centos6, vlan

I am playing with VLAN (Virtual LAN) configuration on CentOS 6.4. I have 2 interfaces, eth0 and eth1.

I have configured 2 VLAN interfaces eth0.20 and eth0.30 as

```
#file: ifcfg-eth0.20
#-------------

VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth0.20
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.20.1
GATEWAY=192.168.20.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no


#file: ifcfg-eth0.30
#-------------
VLAN=yes
DEVICE=eth0.30
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.30.1
GATEWAY=192.168.30.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
```

Then connected a desktop to interface eth0 port using LAN cable and assigned 192.168.30.2/24 IP.

When I try to ping 192.168.30.1 from 192.168.30.2 machine, It shows destination host unreachable. I am also not able to ping 192.168.130.2 from 192.168.30.1.

However `ping -I eth0 192.168.30.2` works fine. Any pointers?

Comment: Hi Amrit! Did you notice that you've tagged both interfaces with VLAN20???     `DEVICE=eth0.20` in your `ifcfg-eth0.30` file

Comment: is the .2 interface 'tagged'? I think it's a tag problem ( .1 tagged vs .2 untagged ) but i've no time to expand the answer atm. No ideas about why " -l " is working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have wrong design.

In VLANs you basically have two tipes of ports: TRUNK PORTS (or tagged ports) and ACCESS PORTS (or untagged ports). TRUNK PORTS should be connected to TRUNK PORTS and ACCESS PORTS to ACCESS PORTS.

Now in your configuration you have a TRUNK port eth0 with two TAGGED VLANS in there - eth0.20 and eth0.30 and ACCESS port on the desktop side (default). You need the same configuration on the other side of the cable (desktop) to have connectivity.  On a desktop configure a TRUNK port with two TAGGED VLANS with subinterfaces for vlan20 (eth0.20 in linux) and vlan30 (eth0.30). Then configure the 192.168.30.2/24 IP on a vlan30 sub interface. Now you will be able to ping 192.168.30.1.

Another option is to use a hardware SWITCH that supports VLANs. Then on a swith you can configure a TRUNK port with two TAGGED VLANS and connect it to Centos side. Again on a switch configure ACCESS port to be in vlan30 and connect it to a desktop. Leave the current configuration on a desktop - 192.168.30.2/24 IP directly on the interface. You will have connectivity.